# Android text will not align to center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TextView` and 3 `Buttons` centered in a `RelativeLayout`, and the text in all three of them is left-justified with the parent center as the leftmost line.

I've tried changing the `gravity` of the `TextView`, `Buttons`, and layout but nothing is working and I'm baffled because I've never seen Android align text like this before.

I want the `Button` text to be centered within each `Button` and the top text to be center-justified.

An image of what it looks like is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lHEd.png

Here's my xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/greeting"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startQuizButton"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="@string/startQuiz"
    android:text="@string/start_quiz" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lessonsButton"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startQuizButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="@string/startLesson"
    android:text="@string/lessonsString" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/viewAllButton"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lessonsButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="@string/showAll"
    android:text="@string/view_all" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I included a `RelativeLayout` because you have it as your parent layout. However, i am not sure that it is needed. See if the following code is what you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Greetings" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Quiz" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lessons" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View all questions" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried your code as-is and it is still aligning the text as in my original screenshot.  I will try removing the relative layout and see what that does.

Comment: Strange, I tested it with an actual phone and what i have posted works. I will post a screen shot of what i am getting.

Comment: I just ran it on a tablet and it works fine.  It was probably just a problem with the emulator and/or Eclipse's layout editor.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

add in button tab   android:gravity="center"...see if it works..

Answer (score 1):

u need to set layout width and height to fill_parent and everything will work fine

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="your text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to centre some text, then you could also do it this way:

```
    <TextView
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
```

here i have changed made it horozontal by using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`which takes a boolean value of true or false, by making it true, it will automatically be centred on all devices 
hope that helps

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" is the correct answer. Thanks @carl